# File Directory and delete file php?

Tags: php, directory

I'm trying to create php script to scan directory and delete file in this directory. I have problem with my scanning file extension is not working right

```
<?php 
 if ($handle = opendir(''))
 {
    echo " Directory handle: $handle \n";
    echo "Entries: \n";


    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) 
    {
        echo" $entry :\n";
        $file_parts = pathinfo($entry);

        switch ($file_parts['extension']) 
        {
            case 'dmg':
                echo "dmg";
                break;

            default:
                echo "no file";
                break;

        }


    }

    closedir($handle);

}


?>
```

Notice: Undefined index: extension in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dir.php on line 13

Comment: I update error Notice: Undefined index: extension in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dir.php on line 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error would be caused if for example the path doesn't have an extension or some error occured.

If you want to retreive the filetype of the files it seems like a roundabout way of doing so when you can just do

```
switch(filetype($dir.$file)){
      case 'dmg' ://And so on
}
```

Here `$dir` would be `/Users/username/Downloads`

Comment: `unlink($dir.$file)` should be what your looking for

Answer (score 1):

Undefined Index means it doesn't exists in the array.

From docs:

> If the options parameter is not passed, an associative array containing the
>   following elements is returned: dirname, basename, extension (if any), and filename.

Your files do have extension?

Also, put '.' (dot) in your `dir` instead of blank space.

You can use `var_dump( $file_parts );` to see what it is.